# Read JSON double dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a string from a JSONObject.

My JSON looks like this :

```
{
    "agent":
    [
        {"name":"stringName1", "value":"stringValue1"},
        {"name":"stringName2", "value":"stringValue2"}
    ]
}
```

I want to get the values from stringName1 and stringName2. So first, I tried to get the "agent" using this :

```
JSONObject agent = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("agent");
```

However, this throws me an error.

Have you got any idea on how to process ?

Comment: "agent" is JSONArray.  `jsonObject.optJSONArray("agent");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to parse a JSON array into a JSON object. Of course it's going to give you errors.

Try this instead:

```
JSONArray agent = jsonObject.getJsonArray("agent");

// To get the actual values, you can do this:
for(int i = 0; i < agent.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = agent.get(i);
    String value1 = object.get("name");
    String value2 = object.get("value");
}
```

Comment: And to get the elements in the Array, use the `get(int)` method. Like: `agent.get(0);`.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I had to change some code but it works ! I changed `agent.size()` to `agent.length()` and `object.get("name")` to `object.getString("name")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String Json=" { agent: [ {name:stringName1, value:stringValue1},{name:stringName2, value:stringValue2}]}";
```

You are parsing Jsonarray in to JsonObject that is why you are getting error.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Json);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("agent");

 for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++)
       {
   String strngNameOne=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
   String stringNameTwo=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
   //System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i));
        }
```